# Filtering a JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for a way to filter my JavaScript Array() `columns` where the parentId is equal to a variable passed into the method.

```
// Array decleration
var columns = []; // Columns
//...
for (var i1 in columns) {
  if (columns[i1].parentId == listItem) {
  //...
```

Could anybody recommend the easiest way to filter this using either plain JavaScript or jQuery to avoid using the if statement as shown above?

Comment: Since you used the term "filter": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter.

Answer (score 5):

```
var filteredColumns = columns.filter(function(column) {
    return column.parentId == listItem;
});
```

Comment: Sometimes, the user might need some info about the indices of the elements as well. Is there any pure JS equivalent of jQuery `grep`?

Comment: @Cupidvogel: if you check the [callback signature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Description) you'll find the index in the second argument

Comment: The callback takes only one argument here, column, right?

Comment: @Cupidvogel: it's not. Please check documentation first for RTFM-alike questions. Thank you.

Comment: @Cupidvogel: Relevant section from the documentation: *"`callback` is invoked with three arguments: (1) the value of the element, (2) the index of the element, (3) the Array object being traversed"*

Answer (score 2):

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5];
result = $.grep(array, function(n,i) {
   return n > 3;
});
```

This will return an array of filtered elements where the results are greater than 3. Here `n` is the element in consideration, and `i` the index of the element. So as per your requirement, the code can run like this:

```
resultArray = $.grep(columns,function(n,i) {
   return n == parentId;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [ES5 Array's filter method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
var filtered = columns.filter(function (item) {
  return item.parentId === listItem
});
```

In the link above there is also a shim for old browsers.

You can also doing that manually:

```
var filtered = [];

for (var i = 0, item; item = columns[i++];)
  if (item.parentId === listItem) filtered.push(item);
```

[Don't use for…in to iterate over Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).